# displaying product info layout

Tags: layout, conversion

I have a product page, currently it is laid out like this:

```
///////////////////////////////////////////
 (Product Title)       /  (product price)
                       /   (add to cart)
(product description)  /  (product image)
```

The image I have is only small, and thus won't take up much room. Are there any industry standards that are well known to outperform conversion rates than others in regards to product page layout. e.g. would I get a better conversion like this:

```
///////////////////////////////////////////
(Product Title)       /  (product price)
  (product image)     /   (add to cart)
             (product description)
```

Any rules of thumb, or ideas of what what the visitor is looking for might also help.

Comment: If you can, I'd say the best bang for your buck might be to get larger images. (But it all depends on what the products are, I suppose).

Comment: The products are B2B, so I am not sure how important the image is to the consumer. But are you saying larger images, and more images, tend to convert better?

Comment: Even in B2B your client is a human and if pictures sell better to consumers why wouldn't that be the case for consumers acting on behalf of a business?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to read [this](http://sixrevisions.com/user-interface/product-page-design/) and [this](http://uxdesign.smashingmagazine.com/2012/01/10/it-works-for-you-a-user-centric-guideline-to-product-pages/). It would be better to have a larger image or a gallery of images.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [this](http://uxdesign.smashingmagazine.com/2012/07/11/better-product-pages-turn-visitors-into-customers/) post.

Attract Attention, Explain The Product, Copywriting and a lot of subject explained to this post.

And I think If you have large image u have to use.